# Undefined method ` yield' - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error:

```
undefined method ` yield' for #<#<Class:0x007fccb4710880>:0x007fccb43f0308>
```

when attempting to render page specific stylesheets using the content_for helper in the application layout.

My index.html.erb template code contains:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "inspection.css" %>
<% end %>
```

My application.html.erb code contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Plastics</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= yield :head %>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running Rails 3.2.15 on Ruby 2.0.0-p195

I have tried switching to Ruby 1.9.3-p429 and other versions of rails including 3.2.12, 3.2.13,..with no luck

I have used this many times in other applications without any issue.

Comment: Please post the whole error stacktrace.

Comment: You need to provide more context here as there must be some other code confusing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you've copied and pasted the "undefined method" error directly from your terminal. There appears to be a space between the open-quote and the word `yield`, which makes me think that Ruby is attempting to call a method with a name that begins with a space.

Ordinarily, that's not easy to do, but you can force it using `send`, as a demonstration:

```
Object.new.send(' yield')
# NoMethodError: undefined method ` yield' for #<Object:0x007fc413258968>
```

So: given the way you've written your layout, why is Ruby/ERb including a space at the beginning of what it thinks is the name of the method?

My guess is that there's some kind of rogue invisible character in there that's throwing off the parsing. Try retyping the two lines that include `yield` statements and see if it starts working.

Comment: That was it. The code editor added something extra that wasn't visible. I deleted and re-created the <%= yield :head %> section of the layout and it works. Marking as accepted.